# Compare 2 large sorted CSV file by 2 columns in java

Tags: java, csv

I have 2 large csv 5GB files suppose FileA and FileB. I want to compare 2 files with their 2 columns in a efficient way. Each file have 63 columns. I want some files as a output explained below :

```
FileA - FileB = File(Unmatched records in FileA)
FileB - FileA = File(Unmatched records in FileB)
FileA ∩ FileB = File(Matched records in both files)
```

I followed a way to solve this problem. I dont know is it efficient or not. A code snippet will be very helpful.

**EDIT:** This is the process i am following. First splitting both files in 75 chunks in 2 different threads.

```
public class SplitFiles implements Runnable {

    private final String sourcePath;
    private final String destPath;

    SplitFiles(String sourcePath, String destPath) {
        this.sourcePath = sourcePath;
        this.destPath = destPath;
    }

    static void readWrite(RandomAccessFile raf, BufferedOutputStream bw,
            long numBytes) throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int) numBytes];
        int val = raf.read(buf);
        if (val != -1) {
            bw.write(buf);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try(RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(sourcePath, "r")) {

            long numSplits = 75; // from user input, extract it from args
            long sourceSize = raf.length();
            long bytesPerSplit = sourceSize / numSplits;
            long remainingBytes = sourceSize % numSplits;

            int maxReadBufferSize = 64 * 1024; // 8KB

            for (int destIx = 1; destIx <= numSplits; destIx++) {
                BufferedOutputStream bw = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(destPath + destIx));
                if (bytesPerSplit > maxReadBufferSize) {
                    long numReads = bytesPerSplit / maxReadBufferSize;
                    long numRemainingRead = bytesPerSplit % maxReadBufferSize;
                    for (int i = 0; i < numReads; i++) {
                        readWrite(raf, bw, maxReadBufferSize);
                    }
                    if (numRemainingRead > 0) {
                        readWrite(raf, bw, numRemainingRead);
                    }
                } else {
                    readWrite(raf, bw, bytesPerSplit);
                }
                bw.close();
            }
            if (remainingBytes > 0) {
                BufferedOutputStream bw = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(destPath + numSplits + 1));
                readWrite(raf, bw, remainingBytes);
                bw.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

2. Then reading both files in 75 threads and comparing it.

   public class CompareFiles implements Runnable {
       private static String SOURCE_A_FILE_NAME = "SplitA/split.";
       private static String SOURCE_B_FILE_NAME = "SplitB/split.";

   ```
   private final int countUntil;

   CompareFiles(int countUntil) {
       this.countUntil = countUntil;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {

       try (BufferedReader inA = Files.newBufferedReader(
               Paths.get(SOURCE_A_FILE_NAME + countUntil),
               Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) {
           for (String lineA; (lineA = inA.readLine()) != null;) {
               try (BufferedReader inB = Files.newBufferedReader(
                       Paths.get(SOURCE_B_FILE_NAME + countUntil),
                       Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) {
                   String[] arrayA = lineA.split("\\|");
                   for (String lineB; (lineB = inB.readLine()) != null;) {
                       String[] arrayB = lineB.split("\\|");
                       if(arrayA[11].equals(arrayB[11]) && arrayA[13].equals(arrayB[13])){
                           writeMatchedRecords();
                       }
                   }
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   public synchronized void writeMatchedRecords(){
       System.out.println("Write files for matched records");
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: `A code snippet will be very helpful.` indeed. How should we suggest changes for your code when you hide it?

Comment: @Tom Sorry i am adding it.

Comment: @Tom stackoverflow editor is not showing it correctly.

Comment: If I understand you code correctly you're comparing "only" comparing chunk x of `A` and chunk x `B` (e.g. chunk 7 of A and chunk 7 B) right? You're not comparing different chunks? If so, it should be better to read the whole chunk of `A` and `B` once and compare the content of the collections. Currently you're reading the whole chunk of `B` for each line of chunk `A`. Also, don't use that many threads. I don't see any performance benefits by that. Try using a thread pool (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) with 5 to 10 threads.